# How to keep Canvas and TextMeshPro vertically above the character

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made `Canvas` and `TextMeshPro` then make this child of Cube object.

```
    GameObject myCanvas = new GameObject();
    myCanvas.name = "TestCanvas";
    myCanvas.AddComponent<Canvas>();
    Canvas canvas = myCanvas.GetComponent<Canvas>();
    canvas.renderMode = RenderMode.WorldSpace;
            

    GameObject myText = new GameObject();
    myText.name = "wibble";
    myText.transform.parent = myCanvas.transform;
    myText.AddComponent<TextMeshPro>();
    TextMeshPro text = myText.GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();
    text.text = "Ta-dah!";
    text.fontSize = 12;
    //text.font = (Font)Resources.Load("MyFont");
    myCanvas.transform.parent = cube.transform; // attache canvas as child of cube.
```

It works so far, however when the cube rounds text also rounds.

I want to keep text always just above the character along Y axis, even when rotation happens.

How can I do this??

Comment: Can you make sure all the transforms of the created objects are correctly configured including the scale. Also, check the real canvas. I think there is a canvas renderer component that is preattached with Canvas when you create it from the editor.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `Billboard` component to the canvas gameobject to handle the rotation and make the canvas always look to the camera.

Billboard component:

using UnityEngine;

```
public class Billboard : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform cam;
    private void Start() {
        cam = Camera.main.transform;
    }
    void LateUpdate() {
        transform.LookAt(transform.position + cam.forward);
    }
}
```

Add the component with `myCanvas.AddComponent<Billboard>();`, your whole script:

```
    GameObject myCanvas = new GameObject();
    myCanvas.name = "TestCanvas";
    myCanvas.AddComponent<Canvas>();
    Canvas canvas = myCanvas.GetComponent<Canvas>();
    canvas.renderMode = RenderMode.WorldSpace;

    myCanvas.AddComponent<Billboard>(); //component added here

    GameObject myText = new GameObject();
    myText.name = "wibble";
    myText.transform.parent = myCanvas.transform;
    myText.AddComponent<TextMeshPro>();
    TextMeshPro text = myText.GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();
    text.text = "Ta-dah!";
    text.fontSize = 12;
    //text.font = (Font)Resources.Load("MyFont");
    myCanvas.transform.parent = transform; // attache canvas as child of cube.
```

Edit:
Image of rotated cube with canvas facinto the camera

[image]

Comment: thank you, I attached Billboard Script to a canvas for testing. text move upward slowly.  `LateUpdate()` is called correctly but, it doesn't look at camera.

Comment: yoou need to set the camera in the billboard component. Updated answer. Added also image with rotated cube and canvas facing to the camera. You'll need also to fix the canvas pivots to the cube's pivots to avoid translaions while rotating to keep the canvas still, but I tried that regarding the canvas facing the camera and it works